# Error: 1252. Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client

Tags: mysql, node.js

```
const mysql = require('mysql2');

const pool = mysql.createPool({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    database: 'node_complete',
    password: 'ankur_54'
});

pool.execute('SELECT * FROM products')
.then(result => {
    console.log(result);
})
.catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

This was my code to obtain data from a MySQL table. But it failed to do so, and instead returned this error. I tried using:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'ankur_54';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

but unfortunately, that didn't work too. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: What's the version of mysql2 package?

Comment: It is ^1.6.5. Its the latest version.